# Plugin or Settings for Python/Pycharms for Code Editor

Tags: python, pycharm

is there a plugin or way that if i press the run button pycharms starts to highlight the code that is currently running step by step so i can see what pycharms is doing

I looked into the pycharms editor settings but didnt really find anything that would help me

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are referring if the debugger tool running the script line by line or just putting breakpoints to check specific values. [check this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/starting-the-debugger-session.html)

Comment: i tried that but it doesnt rly do what i wanted. i saw the same thing in a python tutorial a while ago. the dude in the video started the programm and his editor started to highlight/marked the code that is currently running with yellow

Answer (score 0):

for me there is two possibility :

-use thonny IDE (i dont like it but the debug mod is interresting for that)

-use the tutor module (https://pythontutor.com if you want navigator version)

i only know those solution.